# Is it possible using expresso store?

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, ecommerce, shopping-cart, simple-commerce

I have a requirement and want to check with expresso-store developers whether its possible or not.

Requirements

1. One superadmin who can administer all stores, like adding or deleting a store.
2. Multiple owners can register their own store(s) and should be able to run and maintain their individual store(s). (Like update/publish new products, inventory, sale records, orders, etc)
3. Each owner will be given their own login credentials to manage their stores, products and orders etc.
4. Each store should have a separate URL,for example if my domain URL is www.nisarstores.com,then each store should have a URL like store-1.nisarstores.com,store-2.nisarstores.com etc.
5. Each website will display products related to only that store. For eg. store-1.nisarstores.com will display products only of that store.
6. Orders made on a store should be visible and maintained by respective store admin.
7. The store FE needs to be multi-lingual.

   Hope I was clear in explaining my requirement,so please give your feedback whether this kind of requirement is possible using expresso-store or not.

Cheers
Nisar

Comment: Any one please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no this is not really possible unless you are using MSM or heavily modify the core.

1. This is based upon member groups so someone that is a super admin or has similar privileges should be able to manage the Store settings.
2. Since each store would need to be a MSM site this is not an issue just make sure that each store owner only has access to their MSM site.
3. No problem here this is just default EE membership settings.
4. You would just need to configure your MSM setup properly.
5. Not an issue since store will only display products from the currently active site.
6. Not an issue since orders are site specific.
7. Store does not currently have any support for other third party multi-lingual modules like Publish or Transcribe so you might have a bit of trouble translating things like modifiers, email templates, error messages.

Running a setup like this with using MSM is not an ideal setup in my opinion.